# In an optimal software design, would you ever need to throw InvalidOperationException?

Tags: .net, design

.NET defines the [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) as

> The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

In an optimal software design, would it ever make sense to throw this exception? I would argue that the 'optimal' API prevents any misuse, including, never allowing a method to be called when its state is invalid.

Comment: A program trying to write to a read-only `Stream` would probably get a similar exception. Switching to a class hierarchy with separate `ReadOnlyStream` and `WritableStream` is conceivable - in theory, and we don't know what the consequences will be, until someone tries it out when creating a new framework.

Comment: @rwong I know, this is a rather theoretical question. :) I know in practice the exception does make sense, but then again, who says practice is 'optimal'. ;p

Comment: Related: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1539-OOP-Philosophy-Invalid-State-vs-Invalid-Method-Call.htm

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with your statement, but when designing an API, this type of exception would be useful to a developer who is interfacing with that API.  Whereby the developer would be informed by this exception that his/her code is structured incorrectly.

It would also be best practice to define a verbose message back with the exception indicating what the issue is in plain English (or whatever language is your primary).

Comment: _"Whereby the developer would be informed by this exception that his/her code is structured incorrectly."_ That's how I understood the statement, ... the (rather philosophical) question is whether the ideal API would ever allow you to structure it incorrectly. A classic case is where you expect function calls to be called in order, which could be handled by not allowing to call the second function before the first through separate interfaces.

Comment: @Steve Jeuris - there's the halting problem, which (indirectly) means you can't statically prove every program correct or incorrect. That said, there are dependently typed languages - which can statically prove many more properties of programs when they are compiled instead of relying on run-time checks. I don't know much about them, but I guess they might be capable of providing that InvalidOperationException-free world. One price for that is one we're already paying for some languages anyway (certainly C++, I don't know about C#) - the compilation might never halt. Another is complexity.

Comment: @Steve314 I've never heard of a compilation never 'halting'. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @Steven Did you know that the C++ template processing language is turing complete? That means that it is entirely possible to create a program that only finishes compiling if some non-trivial computation (e.g., determination of the truth or falsity of one of the “more interesting” mathematical conjectures) can be performed. This is awesome/appalling, depending on who you talk to.

Comment: @Steven - as Donal say, C++ templates are Turing complete. You can for example define a recursive template, using specialization to keep that recursion finite. And you can mess up your conditions for the specialization, so maybe there's cases where the recursion is infinite. In Haskell, there's something similar you can do - possibly with typeclasses, more likely with template Haskell - though I don't remember the details. The little bit I know about dependently typed languages is that it involves compile-time programs (probably in the Prolog/declarative logic sense) in the static type system.

Comment: @Steven - there are some examples of Turing complete C++ templates in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189172/c-templates-turing-complete)